# 16 bit barrel shift in Java

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation, rotation, shift

I'm trying to do a rotate right (barrel shift) on an int in Java, e.g.

```
Input:  0000 0000 0110 1001
Output: 1000 0000 0011 0100
```

I know I can do a right shift (`>>`), however I can't work out how to combine this to create a rotate (I'm pretty sure it's possible!).

I think there is a method in `java.lang.Math` but I'm looking to work out how to use shifts only.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Jason: Right ... even a factor of two would do wonders!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a single operation for this. But something like:

```
int x = (x >> 1) | (x << 31)  // or 15 if you really did mean 16-bit
```

would do the trick.

Comment: The question title is 16bit rotate, I think you're pushing the carry too far :-)

Comment: Yeah, "16-bit" and "int" don't really go together in the question. I've added a comment.

Comment: But you would be "polluting" the upper 16 bits (well, some of them) with just the <<15. Probably not important though.

Comment: I think the OP probably wants a 32 bit operation, but otherwise you're absolutely right. Either your technique or doing a final `& 0xFFFF` would do the job.

Comment: I did mean 16-bit so I will add & 0xFFFF, thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: Out of interest, I just discovered `Integer.rotateRight()` and `Integer.rotateLeft()`. I never knew they existed! Of course, they do work on 32-bit quantities, not 16-bit.

Comment: There's a >>> operator which zero fills (instead of using & 0xFFFF).

Answer (score 0):

```
int rotated_by_one = ((value & 1)<<15) | (value >> 1)
```

Comment: Since you're using `&`, I'm pretty sure you're guaranteed to get 0 out of that, whatever the input!

Comment: I've no idea how you edited your post without it showing up as an edit... :-)

Comment: No idea either. Maybe a one char edit doesn't get tracked (edit underflow?) ;-)